# Subversion Installation Error on CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, svn, centos5

I am trying to install subversion on centos 5.8 using`yum install subversion` and it is throwing the error below.

```
.....
....    
Total size: 7.3 M
    Is this ok [y/N]: y
    Downloading Packages:
    Running rpm_check_debug
    ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
    libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by subversion-1.6.11-10.el5_8.x86_64
    libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by subversion-1.6.11-10.el5_8.x86_64
    libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mod_perl-2.0.4-6.el5.x86_64
    apr is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.22-12051516.x86_64
    /usr/lib64/libapr-1.so.0 is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.22-12051516.x86_64
    libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by (installed) mod_perl-2.0.4-6.el5.x86_64
    apr-util is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.22-12051516.x86_64
    /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by (installed) httpd-2.2.22-12051516.x86_64
    Complete!
    (1, [u'Please report this error in http://bugs.centos.org/yum5bug'])
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The last line says that you should report this to the CentOS bugtrackers, which is what you should normally do. It does seem, however, that you installed httpd from a non CentOS repository. If that is the case you will have to let us know how exactly you did that.

In the interim, the answer to your current question is:

- Remove the non-CentOS packages from your machine (httpd in this case)
- Install subversion as you did

Or, alternatively, you can try this:

```
yum downgrade httpd-2.2.3
yum install subversion
```

You should then be able to just rebuild httpd the same way you did before.